# How to find any common existing in Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame likes below:

```
IDS Metric
1,2  100
1,3  200
3    300
...
```

I want to find any two IDs exist in the same row,  for example,  both "1,2" and "1,3" exist in one row, but "2,3" has no direct relationship (means no competition between them in business)

I want to have a function to judge for any two IDs common existing and return True/False.

Just for "judge for any two IDs common existing", I think the following could work:

```
 target_list = ['1', '2']
 df["IDS"].apply(lambda ids: all(id in ids for id in target_list)).any()
 # return True

 target_list = ['2', '3']
 df["IDS"].apply(lambda ids: all(id in ids for id in target_list)).any()
 # return False
```

However, as lambda function will iterate each row in df, and it may be inefficient to iterate all rows, because I only need to judge whether exist.
I hope it should return when first common existing happens.

Could anyone help me about that? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df["IDS"].str.split(',', expand=True).isin(target_list).all(axis=1).any()
```

Another idea with sets:

```
target_list = ['1', '2']
s = set(target_list)

a = any(s.issubset(x.split(',')) for x in df["IDS"])
print (a)
True
```

**Details**:

```
print (df["IDS"].str.split(',', expand=True))
   0     1
0  1     2
1  1     3
2  3  None

print (df["IDS"].str.split(',', expand=True).isin(target_list))
       0      1
0   True   True
1   True  False
2  False  False

print (df["IDS"].str.split(',', expand=True).isin(target_list).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

print (df["IDS"].str.split(',', expand=True).isin(target_list).all(axis=1).any())
True
```

Comment: thx, but could you tell a little detail about why it will be more efficient?  because it seems "isin" will also iterate all rows, while I think it may be more efficient if we find one "isin" true, then no work for rows behind it.

Comment: @linpingta - What is number of rows here? Because it should be faster, because vectorized functions, but depends of data.

Comment: about 1million level~

Comment: @linpingta - Is possible test performance this solution in real data?

Comment: @linpingta - Added another solution with sets